# Jmeter: how to run a thread-group for 1 iteration using "jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group"?

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I have a thread-group in a test plan and I want to perform load run using 100 users. My load configuration should have ramp-up and ramp-down of threads like below:

[image: Load setup]

Except that I don't want to run the load for a specific amount of time as marked in the image. Instead I want to run it for 1 iteration/loop of script. It is possible to run for 1 loop using "simple thread group" but ramp-down is not possible. So is there a way to use both ramp-down and number of loops option for execution of load run in Jmeter?

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating for a while I understood that there is no point in doing ramp-down while giving the number of loops. For example for 10 threads/users I gave 2 loops. Then after completion of 2 loops the thread/user will be shut-down which is indirectly ramp-down.

Answer (score 1):

> We have an option in `basic Thread group` itself, Refer below screenshot

[image]

> Basically `stepping Thread Group` used for load test putting a long time interval, So use `simple thread group` as per your requirement.
>
> But still if you want to use `stepping Thread Group` put very less value for  `Then hold load for`,refer below snapshot

[image]
Conclusion is you need to `use` simple `Thread group` as per your requirement